# Correct way to get golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil

Tags: go, package

It seems the repository has moved from `golang.org/x/tools/astutil` to `golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil`

I'm trying to build [`gore`](https://github.com/motemen/gore) but it cannot found the `astutil`, I have the workaround to get it compiled:

```
mkdir $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ast
ln -s $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/astutil $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/go/ast
```

but is this the correct way to fix this?

I've tried to remove the `x/tools` directory and fetch it again, using this command:

```
rm -rf $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools 
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools
```

but `astutil` still on the same directory (`x/tools/go/astutil`) instead of `x/tools/go/ast/astutil`

I've tried to `go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil` but it seems not working:

```
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
(status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?": found meta tag
main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"
https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at
https://golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?": verifying non-authoritative meta
tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
package golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil?: /home/asd/Dropbox/go/src/
golang.org/x/tools exists but /home/asd/Dropbox/go/src/
golang.org/x/tools/.git does not - stale checkout?
```

What's the correct way to fix this?

My go version: `go version go1.4.1 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\github.com\golang\lint>go get -t -v ./...
golang.org/x/tools/go/exact
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/go/types
golang.org/x/tools/go/gcimporter
github.com/golang/lint
github.com/golang/lint/golint
```

That was enough to at least compile all dependent tools including `golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil`, but not get their sources.

---

For just `astutil`, I also tried:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\go>go get golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil

C:\Users\VonC\prog\go>cd src

C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src>cd golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil

C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\ast\astutil>dir

 Répertoire de C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\golang.org\x\tools\go\ast\astutil

03/02/2015  07:41    <REP>          .
03/02/2015  07:41    <REP>          ..
03/02/2015  07:41            16 003 enclosing.go
03/02/2015  07:41             4 655 enclosing_test.go
03/02/2015  07:41             9 191 imports.go
03/02/2015  07:41            11 035 imports_test.go
03/02/2015  07:41               211 util.go
```

---

If `go get golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil` doesn't work, try with a fresh installation of Go 1.4.2, in a separate and clean Go workspace (meaning a different `GOROOT` for referencing a new installation, and a different `GOPATH`, for referencing an empty and fresh workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my problem:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/
rm -rf go.*

cd $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/
rm -rf *

go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools
go get -u -v golang.org/x/crypto
go get -u -v golang.org/x/image
go get -u -v golang.org/x/mobile
go get -u -v golang.org/x/net
go get -u -v golang.org/x/sys
go get -u -v golang.org/x/text
```

Probably my fault is I `go get` from `code.google.com/p` instead of `golang.org/x`?

Comment: As I told you, a fresh GOPATH is better: no side effect from a previous set of dependencies.