# "go get -t ./...", Travis CI, and installing all go dependencies

Tags: go, travis-ci, dependency-management

In the documentation here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go#Dependency-Management

This is the install dependencies step:

> if go version is greater than or equal to 1.2

```
go get -t ./...
```

My project looks like this:

```
root
---- src
  ---- github.com
  ---- myProject
---- pkg
```

the `GOPATH` is set to `root`

but I am getting this error:

```
package github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda: home/travis/build/path/to/package exists but home/travis/build/path/to/package.git does not - stale checkout?
```

How do I get all the dependencies to install at once like an `npm install` in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get all the dependencies to install at once?

That's what `go get` does... it looks like something might be misconfigured or corrupted in your case.  You could start by trying some things.

- `go get` installs into the first path in the $GOPATH environment variable.  Confirm that it is set to what you want (usually a path ending in a directory named `go`; subdirs `src`, `pkg`, etc. will be created).
- If you're going to use `./...`, make sure you're calling `go get` from the right directory.
- Check to make sure the git root is in the right place
- try using a non-wildcard name/path/address for the package you want to get, instead of `./...`
- try calling `go get` without the `-t` flag

If none of that works, you may be able to solve the problem by deleting the directory (home/travis/build/path/to/package) and trying again -- make sure you aren't deleting any code you worked on, or the git repository/files, unless it's backed up somewhere.

According to [Go tools documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies), you should only need to call

```
go get [packages]
```

to install the named packages along with their dependencies:

> Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies. It then installs the named packages, like 'go install'.

The `...` ellipsis is a wildcard that can expand to match any string.  See section on [Description of Package Lists](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists):

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.

The `./` means "here": so make sure you're running from the right directory if you're going to use `./...`

The `-t` flag is for downloading the packages required to build the tests:

> The -t flag instructs get to also download the packages required to build the tests for the specified packages.

The error you're seeing is related to git.  Sometimes the cause is unknown, but it can often be fixed by deleting the directory and starting again (see, e.g., ["Error to install golint"](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/213) or ["Correct way to get package"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690350/1964690))

(You might also find [this blog post on configuring travis-ci for Go](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/configure-travis-ci-for-go) helpful.)

Comment: Yep, it was a git problem. Doing a `rm` on the dependency directories solved the problem!